# multithread java assign id

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm quite new with Java multi-threading programming.

There is the question: given an integer n, there will be n ids created. Users could call allocate() to get one id from the id pool and call release(int id) after they finish the job.

I'm using a linked hash set here. And only when set.size() == 0 --> wait until the set size is changed. I'm just wondering whether release() should also wait for some conditions or not. Is it okay to add the released id directly into the linked hash set immediately. Or it should use some private lock to hold the linked hashset in both functions instead of using wait() and notify().

I'm wondering is there any one could give me some hints about how these two (wait() & notify() and lock.lock() & lock.unlock()) are different.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// assign id

public class IdManager {
  private LinkedHashSet<Integer> set;

  // constructor
  public IdManager(int n) {
    set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      set.add(i);
    }
  }

  // every time the user calls this function 
  // return the top of linked list
  public int allocate() {
    while(set.size() == 0) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
    int id = set.remove(it.next());
    notifyAll();
    return id;
  }

  // every time the user finishes, release the call
  public int release(int id) {
    // ??? whether lock is required here
    /*
     lock.lock()
     try {
        set.add(id)
     } finally {
        lock.unlock();
     }
    */
    set.add(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you deliberately avoiding higher level multi-threaded constructs built into Java as an exercise?

Comment: I agree- using a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) seems much more natural for this application, and hides explicit locks, etc.. Essentially, you can add ids to the queue when released, and take one from the queue when allocated. Its [put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#put(E)) and [take](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()) methods naturally wait only if necessary.

Comment: @biziclop  Yes, I'm trying to review some concepts and implementations in OS right now. I just wrote some codes before in C and really new to Java. I'm wondering whether my logic is correct in Java. Would you mind giving me some advise?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with those higher-level structs. It seems that I would do some work myself on those constructs then. Thanks a lot for suggestion of LinkedBlockingQueue @augray